# Woman harrassment at Corporate workplace

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, criminal-law, corporate-law, russia

Can a criminal case be filed for the following information provided below against the Top management of the corporate and against immediate supervisor whom she was reporting to with FIR at the police station?

Criminal Case : Woman working at a corporate workplace suffers a train accident. The reason for this could be extreme stress applied on her in completing her work. I.e. immense work pressures.

Working more than 12-14 hours a day continously for 3 weeks and more results in sleep deprivation of the woman causing a train accident leading to Spinal cord vertebrae broken - a extreme painful experience for the woman and for further treatment. The fatal train accident could have resulted in death but by God's grace, her life was saved.

In the above criminal case what will be the punishment to the top management of the corporate? Jail Imprisonment for how much duration, Monetary compensation/penalty etc

The corporate laws will vary from country to country i.e. Russia, USA, Canada, United Kingdom, France, Germany?

Note: The Woman's name, her family details and the corporate workplace where she was working is kept confidential for now as part of privacy.

Comment: Did  they physically push her on to the tracks ? Or have her work in such a noisy setting that she  lost her hearing and couldn’t  hear the train approaching?

Comment: No evidences whether the woman was physically pushed her on the tracks by them but most likely no.

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar: George White was asking what is the connection between the company's actions and the woman's accident.

Comment: Is it against the law for her to work 12-14 hour days? If so, I would think she might have a complaint with the agency that has jurisdiction over labor laws, but not a criminal case.

Comment: As i mention above the connection between the company's actions of putting extreme stress of overloading work caused sleep deprivation leading to train accident. It could also have resulted in death but she suffered a painful experience of Spinal cord vertebrae being broken. But by God's grace she was saved.A single person is overloaded without proper division of work by the immediate supervisor and Top management personnel.

Comment: Can a criminal case complaint with the FIR in the police station be logged against the Top management personnel of the corporate where she faced this issue?. She has suffered a painful experience of Spinal cord vertebrae broken.

Comment: Possibly relevant: does the woman work for the railway?

Comment: I've flagged this as spam based on the random link to Indian lawyers which is at odds with the jurisdiction tags. Happy to retract if the OP can offer a suitable explanation!

Comment: What does FIR mean? For an ambiguous post that basically does not specify *a* jurisdiction (since it mentions a variety of them), this just adds confusion. Also the connection between her deprivation of sleep and the train accident remains unclear: was she driving the train? did she fall on the tracks just when the train was about to pass? The sole fact that she suffered injuries in or nearby a train does not mean that there was a train accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Almost certainly not, but it's possible

The vast majority of jurisdictions might allow this as a civil matter, and it will be a tough hill to climb then.

Criminal prosecution is going to require a bright line between one act and the next.  Millions of people work 14 hours a day and don't get hit by trains.  A train accident is not a reasonable expectation of someone working a lot.  Unless the worker was literally made a slave and forced to work, they had a choice.  A properly motivated prosecutor in the right jurisdicion might come up with a creative way to charge such a case, but it seems very unlikely.